# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, pagerequestmanager

I have a application working fine in one server , I deployed it on another server and getting error

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

This is my assumption I am getting it on this lines, I am not sure , Exactly same code is working fine on another server

My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').pickmeup({
            position: 'bottom',
            hide_on_select: true
        });
    });
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $('.date').pickmeup({
            position: 'bottom',
            hide_on_select: true
        });
    });
</script>
```